# Delphi enumeration individual underlying type as Byte, Word etc without changing the global compiler settings

Tags: delphi

In C# I know that an underlying type for each enumeration type can be defined explicitly and individually, for example:

```cs
enum CoffeeSize : byte
{
    None,
    Tall,
    Venti,
    Grande
};
```

Now I would like to do the same in Delphi.

Does there exist some option to define an underlying type for each enumeration individually, other than by using the *minimum enumeration size* `{$Z}` or `{$MINENUMSIZE}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does there exist some option to define an underlying type for each enumeration individually, other than by using the *minimum enumeration size* `{$Z}` or `{$MINENUMSIZE}`?

No.